# Bitcoin transactions fee increasing

Tags: transactions, address, transaction-fees

For instance take a look at this transaction:

Transaction Size : 1700 bytes

Fee: 133 Sat/Byte

Total: 0.00226898 ~ $33

Outputs: 11

Inputs: 2

[Transaction Link](https://blockchain.info/address/1FVueJMFQrdey2wNfdKQorgbPs5GDkG23d)

what may cause confirming delay, and is sending with higher fee's helps us avoid issues like this? if so, Bitcoin transactions are so expensive , No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this site for average Bitcoin transaction fees
https://bitcoinfees.earn.com

133 Sat/Byte is below the average, therefore not favored by most miners.
In times like this where the network is congested with over [200000 uncomfirmed transactions](https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions), higher fees have higher probabilty of getting through first.

A block can hold at maximum 1MB / 192 bytes = about 5200 transactions, but in reality the average is less than half that number, and [a block takes on average 10 minutes to solve](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Confirmation).
Right now there are more incoming transactions per 10 minutes, than what the miners are capable of solving, hence low fees != prioritized .

Comment: If i've made a transaction with 400 sat/byte and a transaction with 10000000 sat/byte. the miners will accept the transaction with highest fee first?
 in other words if each transaction of a block has 1 btc fee and i've sent a transaction with 400 sat/byte fee the miners will accepts transaction with 1 btc fee before my transaction?

thanks for the help.

Comment: Not always, but when there are a lot of transactions in the mempool the miners tend to be more picky. They can be configured to only accept transactions that are sent with a certain minimum fee.

If you had made two transactions right here and now, one with 400Sat/Byte fee and another transaction with 1BTC/Byte fee,and both sent at the same time. Yes, there is a very HIGH probability  that the 1BTC/Byte will be accepted into a block and confirmed before the transaction with 400Sat/Byte fee.

Comment: However if you made one with 600Sat/byte and another one with 1BTC/Byte, there is a very HIGH probability that both transactions will be accepted into the same block and confirmed at roughly the same time, orders cannot be guaranteed. At https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/ you can tell that transactions sent with fees higher than 520+ Sat/Byte are certain to be included into the next block.